# Unsatisfied Dependency in ConstraintValidator

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi, bean-validation

I'm working on a Jakarta 8 application which runs on Payara 5.2020.4. Its uses CDI all over the place and its working without issues.

Now I want to use Bean Validation.
I have created a `ConstraintValidator` and want to inject some bean to it. This fails with

```
org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at SystemInjecteeImpl(requiredType=Statistic,parent=MyValidator,qualifiers={},position=0,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,872556488)
```

The `Statistic` is injected successfully in many different places but here it fails. The validator is used for instance by an JSF view and there injection works. I came across this [bug in Payara](https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues/2245). But this should be fixed long time ago. So I guess I am missing something.

My validator looks like this:

```java
@Named
public class MyValidator extends ServiceValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ServiceName, String> {
    private final Statistic statistic;

    @Inject
    public MyValidator (Statistic statistic) {
        this.statistic= statistic;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) { ... }

    public void validateName(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String name) throws ValidatorException { ... }
```

This validator is used by a rest resource:

```java
@Path("/rest/{serviceName}/{fileName}")
@POST
@Produces("text/plain")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response doSomething(
    @Context HttpHeaders headers,
    @PathParam("fileName") String fileName,
    @ServiceName @PathParam("serviceName") String serviceName,
    byte[] content)
{ ... }
```

As mentioned when used as follows in a JSF view injection works fine:

```xml
<h:inputText id="ServiceName" required="true" validator = "#{processScanFilesValidator.validateName}" ... >
```

Comment: This looks a lot like a bug. Could it be that `@Named` is wrongly interfering with Beans Validation? Could you try to split in two different components, a Beans `ConstraintValidator` with no `@Named` and a JSF validator with `@Named`? (as a workaround)

Comment: removing `@Named` does not help. The error persists.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. In any case, this looks a lot like a bug, maybe report it to Payara. Other *workarounds* I can think of: (1) try property injection, instead of constructor injection (don't think it will work, but it's easy to give it a try) (2) use programmatic lookup (`CDI.getCurrect().select(...).get()`. Both are horrible, and intended only as workarounds, if there is a bug indeed.